# Gostaria de fazer um limite de pontos para meu jogo desenvolvido em android

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de fazer um limite de pontos para meu game android, exemplo: quando chegar aos 100 pontos ele abrir uma outra tela em branco dizendo por exemplo parabéns! mas estou com dificuldade de fazer isso será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Está é minha classe principal que desenha o elemento na tela!

```
public class GameView extends View implements Runnable {
private final static int INTERVAL = 25;
private boolean running = true;
private Paint paint;
private Inimigo[] inimigos;
private int pontos = 0;
private long tempo = System.currentTimeMillis();

private boolean jogoIniciado = false;

private Bitmap bmpFundo;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint = new Paint();
    Thread minhaThread = new Thread(this);
    minhaThread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    minhaThread.start();
}

public void iniciaJogo() {
    inimigos = new Inimigo[getHeight()/50];
    for (int i = 0; i < inimigos.length; i++) {
        int y = i*-50;
        int x = (int) (Math.random()*(getWidth()-25));
        inimigos[i] = new Inimigo(x, y, getResources());
    }

    bmpFundo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fundo);
    bmpFundo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpFundo, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);

    jogoIniciado = true;
}

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Jogo", "Sleep da Thread");
        }
        update();
    }
}

private void update() {
    if (jogoIniciado==false) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < inimigos.length; i++) {
        inimigos[i].mexe(getHeight(), getWidth());
    }

    //invoca o método draw
    postInvalidate();

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    if (jogoIniciado==false) {
        iniciaJogo();
    }

    //desenha cor de fundo
    //canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmpFundo, 0, 0, paint);

    //define a cor do desenho
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    for (int i = 0; i < inimigos.length; i++) {
        inimigos[i].draw(canvas, paint);
    }

    //defino a cor do texto
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    canvas.drawText("Corações: " + pontos, 20, 40, paint);

    /*int segundos = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - tempo)/1000;
    canvas.drawText("Tempo: " + segundos, 200, 30, paint);*/
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //pega o evento
    int action = event.getAction();
    //pega a posicao do dedo
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //afundou o dedo
        for (int i = 0; i < inimigos.length; i++) {
            if (inimigos[i].colide(x, y)) {
                inimigos[i].setX(-50);
                pontos ++;
            }
        }

    } else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        //soltou o dedo

    } else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        //movimentou o dedo

    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

//termina o jogo
public void release() {
    running = false;
}
```

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPt. Vc diz que "está com dificuldade", mas não diz qual é a dificuldade. Vc não sabe abrir uma outra tela? Vc não sabe comparar o número de pontos? Vc não sabe acumular pontos? Do jeito que a pergunta está, simplesmente não dá pra entender qual é a sua dificuldade. Por favor, edite a pergunta para deixar mais claro isso.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um método que verifica a pontuação passando por parâmentro os  pontos que o usuário ganha no decorrer do jogo, por exemplo `verificaPontuacao(int pontos);`. Aí, dentro do método, você faz a condição para ser redirecionando para outra `Activity` usando [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Com [`startActivity(intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)), você chama sua `classe` para parabenizar o jogador. Este método você irá chamá-lo onde incrementa sua pontuação. Então ficaria assim:

```
 /**
 * Este método verifica se o jogador atingiu 100 pontos.
 * 
 * @param pontos
 */
public void verificaPontuacao(int pontos){
    if(pontos>=100){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Main.class);
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```